# Run UWP app with Cortana with one parameter

Tags: uwp, cortana

I am trying to use Cortana/Start in command line style:

(pressing *Start* an writing:)

> MyApp parameter_I_want_to_pass_to_my_app

This is part my `voiceCommands.xml` file:

```
<Command Name="mycommand">
  <Example> something </Example>
  <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforePhrase">{parameter}</ListenFor>
  <Feedback> Doing something with: {parameter} </Feedback>
  <Navigate />
</Command>
```

`parameter` is specified in same xml:

```
 <PhraseTopic Label="parameter" />
```

It is not working. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voicecommands/support-natural-language-voice-commands-in-cortana) in documentation are some restriction about `PhaseTopic` and using it on beginning of the phase. But these restrictions are only when `RequireAppName` is either `"AfterPhrase"` or `"ExplicitlySpecified"` (in my sample there is `BeforePhrase`)

Everything works fine with when one word is added:

```
<ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforePhrase">word {parameter}</ListenFor>
```

and "command" is changed to:

> MyApp word parameter_I_want_to_pass_to_my_app

It is pointless word...

So question is **How to use Cortana to pass parameter to my app?**

**___EDIT___**

As Jay Zuo - MSFT showed - it is possible to pass parameter to app only with app name.
Issue was somewhere between Cortana and app debuging. List of commands was not refreshed after every app build.

> Uninstalling app, clearing Cortana history, restarting computer and installing app again
>   helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can see from your code is that you are using the wrong **Label** in `PhraseTopic`. In your `Command`, you are using **"parameter"** as your **Label**. So in `PhraseTopic`, the `Label` should also be "parameter" not "destination".

```
<PhraseTopic Label="parameter" />
```

After this, your command should be able to work. Using [Cortana voice command sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) for example, once we add the `Command` and `PhraseTopic` into its VCD file, we can then launch the app with Cortana by saying something like:

**"adventure works this is a test"**
[image]

You may need to check if the **AppName** is recognized correctly. For example, here, a working voice command must starts with **"adventure works"**. If your speaking is recognized as **"AdventureWorks this is a test"** then it won't work.

As you may have known, an easy way to test the voice command you've registered is typing the command in Cortana search box like the following:

[image]

With above input, there should be no problem.

Comment: "destination" is just residue after making question sample with "parameter". It is correct in my app. Good point is that it should work. But it does not work in my case. Cortana is somehow confused when changing voiceCommand.xml... Is there any way how to re-fresh voice commands in Cortana?